# What is the safest way to initialize bash arrays with quoted values from function output?

Tags: arrays, bash, interpolation

I prefer to program my bash scripts to be as procedural as possible.  One difficulty I've encountered in trying to do so happens when passing array data between functions, a task that's not well supported in bash.

As an example, it's trivial to initial an array in bash with multiple hard-coded, quoted values, each of which may contain multiple words:

```
declare -a LINES=( "Hello there" "loyal user" )
echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
# Line 0: 'Hello there'
# Line 1: 'Loyal user'
```

However, replacing such hard-coded values with the output of a function seems to not work so well:

```
getLines() {
    echo "\"Hello there\" \"loyal user\""
}

local LINE_STR=$( getLines )
declare -a LINES=( ${LINE_STR} )
echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
# Line 0: '"Hello'
# Line 1: 'there"'
```

I've tried almost every permutation of allowed bash statements to overcome this problem.  The one approach that seems to work well is 'eval':

```
local LINE_STR=$( getLines )
eval declare -a LINES=( ${LINE_STR} )
echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
# Line 0: 'Hello there'
# Line 1: 'loyal user'
```

However, this approach is wrought with security concerns, as demonstrated here:

```
emulateUnsafeInput() {
    echo "\"\`whoami\` just got haxxored\" \"Hahaha!\""
}

local LINE_STR=$( emulateUnsafeInput )
eval declare -a LINES=( "${LINE_STR}" )
echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
# Line 0: 'root just got haxxored'
# Line 1: 'Hahaha!'
```

'read -a' seems like a possible solution, although a problematic one because 'read' will operate in a sub-shell when data is piped into it, effectively separating its variable stack from the one of the calling script.

What solutions should I consider to mitigate the security concerns of the 'eval' approach?  I've included the following script which demonstrates the myriad of approaches I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

getLines() {
    echo "\"Hello there\" \"loyal user\""
}

emulateUnsafeInput() {
    echo "\"\`whoami\` just got haxxored\" \"Hahaha!\""
}

execute() {
(
    echo Test 01
    declare -a LINES=( "Hello there" "loyal user" )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: 'Hello there'
    # Line 1: 'loyal user'
);(
    echo Test 02
    local LINE_STR=$( getLines )
    declare -a LINES=( ${LINE_STR} )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: '"Hello'
    # Line 1: 'there"'
);(
    echo Test 03
    local LINE_STR=$( getLines )
    declare -a LINES=( "${LINE_STR}" )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: '"Hello there" "loyal user"'
    # Line 1: ''
);(
    echo Test 04
    local LINE_STR=$( getLines )
    eval declare -a LINES=( ${LINE_STR} )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: 'Hello there'
    # Line 1: 'loyal user'
);(
    echo Test 05
    local LINE_STR=$( getLines )
    eval declare -a LINES=( "${LINE_STR}" )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: 'Hello there'
    # Line 1: 'loyal user'
);(
    echo Test 06
    local LINE_STR=$( getLines )
    declare -a LINES=( $( echo ${LINE_STR} ) )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: '"Hello'
    # Line 1: 'there"'
);(
    echo Test 07
    local LINE_STR=$( getLines )
    declare -a LINES=( $( echo "${LINE_STR}" ) )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: '"Hello'
    # Line 1: 'there"'
);(
    echo Test 08
    local LINE_STR=$( getLines )
    declare -a LINES=( $( eval echo ${LINE_STR} ) )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: 'Hello'
    # Line 1: 'there'
);(
    echo Test 09
    local LINE_STR=$( getLines )
    declare -a LINES=( $( eval echo "${LINE_STR}" ) )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: 'Hello'
    # Line 1: 'there'
);(
    echo Test 10
    local LINE_STR=$( emulateUnsafeInput )
    eval declare -a LINES=( ${LINE_STR} )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: 'root just got haxxored'
    # Line 1: 'Hahaha!'
);(
    echo Test 11
    local LINE_STR=$( emulateUnsafeInput )
    eval declare -a LINES=( "${LINE_STR}" )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: 'root just got haxxored'
    # Line 1: 'Hahaha!'
);(
    echo Test 12
    local LINE_STR=$( emulateUnsafeInput )
    declare -a LINES=( $( eval echo ${LINE_STR} ) )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: 'root'
    # Line 1: 'just'
);(
    echo Test 13
    local LINE_STR=$( emulateUnsafeInput )
    declare -a LINES=( $( eval echo "${LINE_STR}" ) )
    echo "Line 0: '${LINES[0]}'"
    echo "Line 1: '${LINES[1]}'"
    # Line 0: 'root'
    # Line 1: 'just'
)
}

execute
```

Answer (score 2):

The following [handles spaces in array elements correctly](http://notes-matthewlmcclure.blogspot.com/2009/10/return-array-from-bash-function.html):

```
#! /bin/bash

# $ ./return_an_array.sh 
# ./return_an_array.sh: line 9: declare: returned_array: not found
# declare -a returned_array='([0]="one" [1]="two three")'

return_an_array()
{
    local -a an_array=( 'one' 'two three' )
    declare -p an_array
}

declare -p returned_array
eval $(return_an_array | sed -e 's/^\(declare -a \)[^=]*=/\1 returned_array=/')
declare -p returned_array
```

Answer (score 1):

For the data function use `echo -e` and separating data with newlines:

```
getLines() { echo -e "\"Hello there\"\n\"loyal user\""; }
```

To read the data, use process substitution and redirection:

```
i=0
while read -r
do
    arr[i++]=$REPLY
done < <(getLines)
# Line 0: '"Hello there"'
# Line 1: '"loyal user"'
```

This leaves the quotes around the strings, though.

Based on techniques from [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005).

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about arbitrary, malicious data from functions, you should simply expect and parse strings with the `\0` (aka. `NUL`) separator. It's the *only* character which can not be part of any variables, so there's no way there will be collisions with actual data.

```
haxxorz() {
    printf '%s\0' whoami
    printf '%s\0' '\`whoami\`'
    printf '%s\0' "\`whoami\`"
    printf '%s\0' "\"\`whoami\` is haxxor-proof"'!'"\""
    printf '%s' 'Trying to poison the $REPLY variable with a missing separator'
}

index=0
while IFS= read -r -d '' || [ -n "$REPLY" ]
do
    array[index++]="$REPLY"
done < <(haxxorz)

for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done

echo "${REPLY:-REPLY is empty}"
```

Result:

```
whoami
\`whoami\`
`whoami`
"`whoami` is haxxor-proof!"
Trying to poison the $REPLY variable with a missing separator
REPLY is empty
```

I love it when a plan comes together!